# how to create XML Editor for MAC?

Tags: macos

I need to build a XML EDITOR for MAC?

Can anybody help me in this regard? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, where to begin?

First of all, take note of Michael Shimmins' answer; you'll need Xcode to do the program. While his answer mentions Java, I would avoid that, and go for Objective-C.

As for the application itself, it all depends on how you want to edit the XML; some more information would be great on this point.

If you want a text-editor style XML editor, you should probably start with a simple Document-Based Cocoa Application; and put in an `NSTextView`, and see where you can go from there; if, on the other hand, you want a tree-based editor; you'll need to have a look at `NSOutlineView` and `NSXMLDocument`, part of the `NSXML` bits of Cocoa.

Then you'll need to design your application, program it, test it, and finally, if applicable, release it.

Comment: Any link to a tutorial on this topic would be nice...I want to build it using objective c.

Comment: Do you *know* Objective-C? If not, start there. There are plenty of introductions floating around the web, I'd recommend the one from Apple (http://developer.apple.com has the goods).

Comment: I know objective-C and I know how to use Xcode. I have not used it to develop apps for MAC though I use it for developing iphone apps.

Comment: The flow is pretty much the same, except that you start with a different project type; and slightly different UI paradigms (although they are *fairly* similar).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very open ended question.

You can build applications for Mac OS X in a variety of languages/technologies.  Common choices include:

- Objective-C
- Java

If you're developing in Objective-C (the native development platform for OS X), you'll need [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) from Apple.

You'll probably want to learn Cocoa (the UI framework on OS X) and the core libraries (Core Foundation, Core Data etc).

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to buy, not build.

There are also free XML editors, or free versions of commercial XML Editors.